# La función the_field de los campos personalizados no me funciona en wordpress, cómo solucionarlo

Tags: php, wordpress, backend

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Estoy llamando los parámetros en cada lugar indicado biografia, titulo perfil del entrenador, nombre y apellido pero no me muestra nada al guardar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se puede observar en esta imagen que los parámetros agregados no muestran nada de información.

Answer (score -1):

Debes poner "echo" delante de  the_field():

```
<?php echo the_field('biografia'); ?>
```